# Compact Framework Current Folder

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

How do I know which is the current folder of an App?

I mean... Is there a way to know where is the exe located from the running code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string fullAppName = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase;
string fullAppPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullAppName);
```

Answer (score 9):

Windows Mobile doesn't have the concept of a current folder. The "current folder" is basically always set to be the root of the filesystem, no matter where your application is located.

To get the path your application is located, you can use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`, and the `CodeBase` property or `GetName()` method

Answer (score 5):

Don't fight the system.

Microsoft does not want you to use the program files folder for anything other then assemblies. Config files should go in Application Data, Save files and the like which users need to know about go in My Documents.

jalf's answer will work but you are fighting the system. Unless their is a really good reason why you want to know what folder your assembly is in then I would suggest against it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885629.aspx)

In the below sample, the method `GetExecutablePath` returns the location of the exe, and `GetStartupPath` returns the directory of the exe.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    [DllImport("coredll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern uint GetModuleFileName(IntPtr hModule, StringBuilder lpFilename, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int nSize);

    [DllImport("coredll")]
    public static extern uint FormatMessage([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FormatMessageFlags dwFlags, IntPtr lpSource, uint dwMessageId, uint dwLanguageId, out IntPtr lpBuffer, uint nSize, IntPtr Arguments);

    [DllImport("coredll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LocalFree(IntPtr hMem);

    [Flags]
    internal enum FormatMessageFlags : uint
    {
        AllocateBuffer = 256,
        FromSystem = 4096,
        IgnoreInserts = 512
    }

    public static string GetModuleFileName(IntPtr hModule)
    {
        StringBuilder lpFilename = new StringBuilder(short.MaxValue);
        uint num = GetModuleFileName(hModule, lpFilename, lpFilename.Capacity);
        if (num == 0)
        {
            throw CreateWin32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
        return lpFilename.ToString();
    }

    private static Win32Exception CreateWin32Exception(int error)
    {
        IntPtr buffer = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            if (FormatMessage(FormatMessageFlags.IgnoreInserts | FormatMessageFlags.FromSystem | FormatMessageFlags.AllocateBuffer, IntPtr.Zero, (uint)error, 0, out buffer, 0, IntPtr.Zero) == 0)
            {
                return new Win32Exception();
            }
            return new Win32Exception(error, Marshal.PtrToStringUni(buffer));
        }
        finally
        {
            if (buffer != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                LocalFree(buffer);
            }
        }
    }

    public static string GetStartupPath()
    {
        return Path.GetDirectoryName(GetExecutablePath());
    }

    public static string GetExecutablePath()
    {
        return GetModuleFileName(IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a really big hammer for such a small nail.

Answer (score 2):

The following is correct.

```
string fullAppName = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase;
fullAppPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullAppName);
```

For equivalent code in other languages Refer to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229654.aspx)